# How to assign a string value to a string variable in C++

Tags: c++, string

Shouldn't this work?

```
string s;
s = "some string";
```

Comment: @David: I agree that the question is somewhat terse, but for all we know Phenom could have tried and got an error message: `int main() { string s; s = "some string"; }` will give error messages which might seem cryptic to a novice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes!

It's default constructing a string, then assigning it from a `const char*`.

(Why did you post this question?... did you at least try it?)

Comment: I was having a problem doing it with vectors. This answer helped me to find the problem, which lay elsewhere, and had to do with how vectors work.

Comment: Ah, I see - glad it helped.  Next time, you might post a little more detail about your problem and we'd probably enjoy helping you with that too :)

Answer (score 14):

> Shouldn't this work?
>
> ```
> string s;
> s = "some string";
> ```

Well, actually it's spelled `std::string`, but if you have a `using namespace std;` ([absolutely evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/140719)) or `using std::string;` (somewhat less evil) before that, it should work - provided that you also have a `#include <string>` at the top of your file.

Note, however, that it is wasteful to first initialize `s` to be an empty string, just to replace that value in the very next statement. (And if efficiency wasn't your concern, why would you program in C++?) Better would be to initialize `s` to the right value immediately:

```
std::string s = "some string"
```

or

```
std::string s("some string");
```

Comment: well sometimes that is not possible. (like when you know the value of the string way after you declare it)

Comment: @KansaiRobot (_Note:_ Local variables are _defined_. Yes, [a definition is a declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/140719), too. But then, while we are apes, too, and mammals, and vertebrates, etc., we still think and speak of ourselves as humans.) If you do not know the value to initialize a string with, define the string later, if possible. (If it is not possible, then that's what default constructors are there for.)

Answer (score -2):

use header file 
    string.h or bits/stdc++.h
then try 
s.assign("some string");

Comment: `<string.h>` is not for `std::string`. And `bits/…` is problematic too. Finally, using `.assign()` changes exactly nothing.